# Python flask и arduino ethernet shiled

Tags: flask, arduino, ethernet

такая проблема:
Ethernet shield делает запросы на сервер на python flask,
но после 15-20 запросов плата зависает, в техподдержке мне сказали, что сервер не закрывает сокет. Как это исправить или дело не в этом? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А предоставить код вы можете? Ведь проблема может быть 1) в коде 2) в инфраструктуре (подключении)

Comment: Hard reset. https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/arduino-tips-and-tricks#p14